# How to hide the view of a UIImageView when no image

Tags: ios, url, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in which it loaded an `image` from `url`. My problem is that when the url is `empty`, the view appears filling space of the screen without nothing.

I want to know how I can hide this view is the string with the url is empty.

Comment: why dont you just check if URL is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check :

```
NSString *URL = [YourURL absoluteString];

if(![URL isEqualToString:@"null"])
{
   imageView.image=@"img.png";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of your URL string returned to know if it's empty like this

```
NSString *yourURL

if ([yourUrl length]<1){

imageView.hidden = YES;

}else{

//show imageview with the image

}
```

I hope this helps